# How to add a new key-value pair to each object in a JSON array

Tags: python, json

How can I add a new key-value pair to each of the objects in a JSON array as shown below? I tried using the below code, but the result is separated instead of being in the same, original array.

```py
import json

json_var = '''{
"information" : {
  "info_id"          : "8878",
  "info_name"        : "Stackoverflow"
},

"env" : {
  "env_name"           : "UAT",
  "env_type"           : "Staging"
},

"services" : [
  {
    "service_name"         : "stack1",
    "service_version"     : "1"
  },
  {
    "service_name"         : "stack2",
    "service_version"     : "2"
  },  
  {
    "service_name"         : "stack3",
    "service_version"     : "3"
  }
 ]
}'''

y = {"pin":110096}
entry = json.loads(json_var)

for i in entry['services']:
      i.update(y)
      print(json.dumps(i))
```

Actual output:

```json
{"service_name": "stack1", "service_version": "1", "pin": 110096}
{"service_name": "stack2", "service_version": "2", "pin": 110096}
{"service_name": "stack3", "service_version": "3", "pin": 110096}
```

Expected output:

```
[
{"service_name": "stack1", 
  "service_version": "1", 
  "pin": 110096
},
{"service_name": "stack2",
 "service_version": "2",
 "pin": 110096
},
{"service_name": "stack3",
 "service_version": "3",
 "pin": 110096
}
]
```

Please advise on how to modify the above code or provide new code to achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue is with the placement of your `print()` statement. It should be outside of the `for` loop, and you should be printing `entry['services']` rather than `i`. This allows you to print all of updated entries at once, rather than one at a time.

```py
y = {"pin":110096}
entry = json.loads(json_var)

for i in entry['services']:
    i.update(y)

print(json.dumps(entry['services']))
```

This outputs:

```py
[{"service_name": "stack1", "service_version": "1", "pin": 110096},
{"service_name": "stack2", "service_version": "2", "pin": 110096},
{"service_name": "stack3", "service_version": "3", "pin": 110096}]
```